# Spring inner bean instantiation

Tags: java, spring

first of all please refer to this tutorial i've been reading.

[Spring Injecting Inner Bean](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_injecting_inner_beans.htm)

I've been following that tutorial because it seems much easier to understand than other tutorials and guides over the internet.

So i am having trouble grasping the concept of inner bean here. It was not explicitly indicated on that tutorial (or i must've miss something on spring docus). So do please point me or explain to me the following;

1.) In TextEditor.java, it has a method `setSpellChecker(SpellChecker spellChecker)`, and looking at the final output it displayed 3 messages. Particulalry **"Inside setSpellChecker."**, **How was it displayed where in fact SpellChecker class has no constructor, its a setter method. does this mean upon setting of property spellChecker, setter method was called?**

Disclaimer: 
 I am new to spring and even though there is a documentation on spring site. I can't consume them all and expect that i will know all of its concept so i learn by doing and testing stuff. And this is one of those time im stuck and can't move on. wanted to learn in step by step before i go do advance stuff.

UPDATES
 - modified the question, i've reading it over and over again. see new question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Inside setSpellChecker."** is printed because `spellChecker` bean is injected into `TextEditor` using setter injection as  `<property>` tag is used in `Beans.xml`.

> Below steps are executed to create bean of `TextEditor`.

1. Create instance of `spellChecker` (inner bean) so it prints **'Inside SpellChecker constructor.`**
2. Set `spellChecker` bean into `TextEditor` using `TextEditor.setSpellChecker()` as we are using setter injection.When `TextEditor.setSpellChecker()` gets called, it prints **"Inside setSpellChecker"**  and assigns `spellChecker` `TextEditor.spellChecker`.

[More on setter injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-setter-injection).

Comment: i see spot on mate. So there is a setter injection beside the constructor injection.. BTW just to add to it..  when you have multiple setter, all gets to be execution on injection?

Comment: @lemoncodes Setter injection will be executed for all fields of bean for which `<property>` tag is used in `Beans.xml`.e.g. Consider If no `<property>` was not defined for `TextEditor.spellChecker` in `Beans.xml` then  `TextEditor.spellChecker` would be null as no setter method will get called.